# How to convert data with M and B at the end back to numbers in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe, I want to convert them to million and billion. How can I restore it back to a number?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j77lf.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
df["views"] = (map(eval, df["views"].str.replace("M", "*10**9")))
```

Here I am firstly replacing all "M" with "10**9". If you do `eval("5*10**9")` you would get 5 billion. That's because the `eval` function converts any string to a Python statement. Because of this functionality, I pass each item in the replaced series in the `eval` function using the `map` function, convert it into a `list` and store it in `df["views"]`.

If you just want to make "674M" to "674B", do this -

```
df["views"] = df["views"].str.replace("M", "B")
```

And please put the dataframe in the question as text or table.